# pytest "fixture 'url' not found" while no fixture is used

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, allure

When I try to execute tests (`python3 -m pytest dir1/subdir/test.py`) I get error:

```
__________________________ ERROR at setup of testcase __________________________
file /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allure_commons/_allure.py, line 50
  def testcase(url, name=None):
E       fixture 'url' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_xml_property, recwarn, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory, worker_id
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allure_commons/_allure.py:50
=========================== 1 error in 0.40 seconds ============================
```

but I do NOT use any "url" fixture in the code.
I even tried to rename every "url" variable in project but problem still exists.

Installed requirements:

```
allure-pytest==2.8.16
allure-python-commons==2.8.16
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==19.3.0
axe-selenium-python==2.1.6
certifi==2020.4.5.2
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
configparser==5.0.0
coverage==5.1
crayons==0.3.1
cx-Oracle==7.3.0
Faker==4.1.0
flaky==3.6.1
idna==2.9
importlib-metadata==1.6.1
iso3166==1.0.1
more-itertools==8.3.0
packaging==20.4
page-objects==1.1.0
parameterized==0.7.4
pluggy==0.13.1
py==1.8.1
pycountry==19.8.18
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==5.4.3
python-dateutil==2.8.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.23.0
schwifty==2020.5.3
selenium==3.141.0
simple-value-object==1.3
six==1.15.0
text-unidecode==1.3
urllib3==1.25.9
wcwidth==0.2.4
webdriver-manager==2.5.3
zipp==3.1.0
```

Comment: What is the current directory you are executing the tests from? Is it `/`?

Comment: Yes, my code structure is something like:
`base_dir/src/project1/tests/my_test.py`

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]
I finally found a solution. It turns out that I had to add `__test__ = True` to my tests classes.

FYI: All of my tests are inherited from `TestBase(unittest.TestCase)` class 
which has attribute `__test__ = False`. Purpose of this attribute is to not duplicate test execution - once from base and second from inherited class.
More details: https://www.termitnjak.com/en/blog/pytest-inheritance-problems